# Cannot run PySpark (not using interactive shell) on Cloudera VM

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera-quickstart-vm

When I follow [this example](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_develop_run.html) and try to use the command `spark-submit` within the cloudera vm envirionrment, I constantly get the following error:

```
ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=cloudera, access=WRITE, inode="/user/spark/applicationHistory":spark:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
....
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cloudera/wordcount.py", line 9, in <module>
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 172, in _do_init
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 235, in _initialize_context
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1064, in __call__
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=cloudera, access=WRITE, inode="/user/spark/applicationHistory":spark:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

I have tried these two commands:

1, `$ spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 1g \ --name wordcount --conf "spark.app.id=wordcount" wordcount.py hdfs://namenode_host:8020/path/to/inputfile.txt`

2, `$ spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 1g \ --name wordcount --conf "spark.app.id=wordcount" wordcount.py inputfile.txt`

Can somebody help?

Comment: Looks like you need to run `chmod` or `chown` to give your user some permissions

Comment: As @cricket_007 mentioned, it is a permission issue. It seems like Spark's `applicationHistory` does not have enough permissions. You can try providing permissions like so - `sudo -u spark hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/spark/applicationHistory`

Answer (score 1):

Try running with the following environment variable:

```
HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs spark-submit <your command>
```